# Adding "diagrams" to figures and tables / duplicate float?

Tags: floats, koma-script, tocbasic

I am writing a paper using KOMA script (scrartcl) and have a lot of tables, figures and diagrams: the latter really are nothing but figures but need to be counted separately and get their own list of diagrams in the appendix.

How do I "clone" the figure environment, so to speak, complete with counter and everything? I have, say, Figure 1, Figure 2, Diagram 1, Figure 3, Diagram 2 etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using a KOMA-Script class that loads `tocbasic` to manage floats and lists of floats (and nonfloats). So you can use this package to declare a new list:

```
\DeclareNewTOC[
  type=diagram,
  float,
  floattype=4,
  floatpos=htb,
  name=Diagram,
  listname={List of Diagrams},
  tocentrynumwidth=2.3em,% like figures and tables
  tocentryindent=1.5em,% like figures and tables
]{lod}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\usepackage{graphicx}

\DeclareNewTOC[
  type=diagram,
  float,
  floattype=4,
  floatpos=htb,
  name=Diagram,
  listname={List of Diagrams},
  tocentrynumwidth=2.3em,% like figures and tables
  tocentryindent=1.5em,% like figures and tables
]{dia}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\listofdiagrams
\section{A Section}
\blindtext
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}
  \caption{First figure}
\end{figure}
\Blindtext
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}
  \caption{Second figure}
\end{figure}
\blindtext
\begin{diagram}
  \centering
  \rule{5cm}{2cm}
  \caption{First diagram}
\end{diagram}
\Blindtext
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}
  \caption{Third figure}
\end{figure}
\Blindtext
\begin{diagram}
  \centering
  \rule{5cm}{2cm}
  \caption{Second diagram}
\end{diagram}
\end{document}
```